# Como fazer login em outra página via php?

Tags: php, login, auth

Tenho um painel de rádio com interface web e nele tem uma função que é fundamental para os locutores usarem. o problema é que essa interface me permite registrar apenas 1 usuário. No caso, eu (Administrador).

E eu não posso dar essa senha para a galera por motivos óbvios. 
Então gostaria de fazer uma segunda página que após os locutores se conectarem, eles cliquem em um botão e esse botão envia o login e senha para o painel da rádio e abre um link que tem lá. Tudo sem que o locutor precise fornecer login e senha para acessar uma função no painel.

Minha única dúvida é como fazer este botão com essa função.

Vou fazer uma espécie de algoritmo para vocês entenderem:
fiz tudo em BR mesmo, sem nenhuma linguagem. Agradeço desde já.

```
var login = "login do painel"
var senha = "senha do painel" 
var sitePainel = "http://painel.com/login"
var funcao = "http://painel.com/reset.cgi"

Se clicarNoBotão (enviar login + senha)
   para sitePainel
se (login com sucesso)
   executar funcao
```

Comment: Você não irá conseguir nada com esse tipo de conteúdo na pergunta. Está muito "Vago": Minha única dúvida é como fazer este botão com essa função.

Comment: Vou ser mais direto. realmente não dá para add outros usuários. é um código que não posso modificar nem nada do tipo, pra ser mais exato é o painel do shoutcast. e existe em outras rádios um painel que tem a função "kickar o locutor" e ao clicar nesse botão (creio eu) que ele faz login no painel do shoutcast e abre o link que executa a função de kickar o locutor.

Comment: Tenho um amigo que disse que posso fazer isso usando auth do php. como no momento ele está sem tempo para fazer um modelo esqueleto, resolvi perguntar aqui para vocês para adiantar.